# Trying to count number of customers in system

Tags: logic, anylogic

im trying to figure out a way to count how many customers remain in the system after it runs for 30hrs i tried using the statistic property on the Agent but i think im doing it wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUho.png)

Comment: hey, would be good if you show your Statistics setup and let us know what you mean by "remain in the system". Impossible to answer otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the agent statistics, use

```
!item.inState(item.exit)
```

Assuming customers in the system are the ones who are not in the exit state.

[image: statistics]
then you can calculate this statistic using (assuming your population is called customers)

```
customers.remaining()
```